# Error C2086: redefinition

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some issues with my C++ code. I'm trying to now split a header file which has definitions and declarations of some char pointers (previously strings but i've been having some CRT issues so changing them to a char pointer). Since I've changed them to a char pointer, i'm getting redefinition errors.

Test.h

```
#pragma once
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "TestConstantsHeader.cpp"

namespace DataVerifier
{
    class DllExport CDataVerifier
    {
    public:
        CDataVerifier();
        ~CDataVerifier();

        //! @brief A function that processes the messages
        void Process();
    };
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

using namespace DataVerifier;

CDataVerifier::CDataVerifier()
{
}

CDataVerifier::~CDataVerifier(){}

void CDataVerifier::Process()
{
    const char* strTmp = Structure::strHTMLTemplate;
    strTmp = "hello";
    std::cout << strTmp;
}
```

TestConstantsHeader.h

```
#pragma once
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

#include <iostream>

namespace DataVerifier
{
    namespace Structure
    {
        const char *strHTMLTemplate;/* = "<doctype html>"
            "<html lang=\"en\">"
            "<head>"
            "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>"
            "<title>Data Verifier Test Results - {@testdesc}</title>"
            "<style>"
            "body {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F4;"
            "\tcolor: #1E1E1F;"
            "\tfont-family: \"Segoe UI\",Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 0;"
            "}"
            "h1 {"
            "\tbackground-color: #E2E2E2;"
            "\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #C1C1C2;"
            "\tcolor: #201F20;"
            "\tfont-size: 21pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 10px 0 10px 10px;"
            "}"
            "h2 {"
            "\tfont-size: 18pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
            "}"
            "h3 {"
            "\tbackground-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
            "\tfont-size: 15pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
            "}"
            "a {"
            "\tcolor: #1382CE;"
            "}"
            "table {"
            "\tborder-collapse: collapse;"
            "\tborder-spacing: 0;"
            "\tfont-size: 10pt;"
            "}"
            "table th {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E7E8;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tpadding: 3px 6px;"
            "\ttext-align: left;"
            "\ttext-decoration: none;"
            "}"
            "table td {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F8;"
            "\tborder: 1px solid #E7E7E8;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 3px 6px 5px 5px;"
            "\tvertical-align: top;"
            "}"
            ""
            ".textCentered {"
            "\ttext-align: center;"
            "}"
            ".messageCell {"
            "\twidth: 100;"
            "}"
            "#content {"
            "\tpadding: 0 12px 12px;"
            "}"
            "#overview table {"
            "\tmax-width: 75;"
            "\twidth: auto;"
            "}"
            "#messages table {"
            "\twidth: 97;"
            "}"
            "</style>"
            "</head>"
            "<body>"
            "<div id=\"big_wrapper\">"
            "\t<h1>Test Results - {@testdesc}</h1>"
            "\t<table>"
            "{@eeddata}"
            "\t</table>"
            "</body>"
            "</html>";*/
    }
}
```

TestConstantsHeader.cpp

```
#include "TestConstantsHeader.h"

namespace DataVerifier
{
    namespace Structure
    {
        const char *strHTMLTemplate = "<doctype html>"
            "<html lang=\"en\">"
            "<head>"
            "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>"
            "<title>Data Verifier Test Results - {@testdesc}</title>"
            "<style>"
            "body {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F4;"
            "\tcolor: #1E1E1F;"
            "\tfont-family: \"Segoe UI\",Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 0;"
            "}"
            "h1 {"
            "\tbackground-color: #E2E2E2;"
            "\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #C1C1C2;"
            "\tcolor: #201F20;"
            "\tfont-size: 21pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 10px 0 10px 10px;"
            "}"
            "h2 {"
            "\tfont-size: 18pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
            "}"
            "h3 {"
            "\tbackground-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
            "\tfont-size: 15pt;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
            "}"
            "a {"
            "\tcolor: #1382CE;"
            "}"
            "table {"
            "\tborder-collapse: collapse;"
            "\tborder-spacing: 0;"
            "\tfont-size: 10pt;"
            "}"
            "table th {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E7E8;"
            "\tfont-weight: normal;"
            "\tpadding: 3px 6px;"
            "\ttext-align: left;"
            "\ttext-decoration: none;"
            "}"
            "table td {"
            "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F8;"
            "\tborder: 1px solid #E7E7E8;"
            "\tmargin: 0;"
            "\tpadding: 3px 6px 5px 5px;"
            "\tvertical-align: top;"
            "}"
            ""
            ".textCentered {"
            "\ttext-align: center;"
            "}"
            ".messageCell {"
            "\twidth: 100;"
            "}"
            "#content {"
            "\tpadding: 0 12px 12px;"
            "}"
            "#overview table {"
            "\tmax-width: 75;"
            "\twidth: auto;"
            "}"
            "#messages table {"
            "\twidth: 97;"
            "}"
            "</style>"
            "</head>"
            "<body>"
            "<div id=\"big_wrapper\">"
            "\t<h1>Test Results - {@testdesc}</h1>"
            "\t<table>"
            "{@eeddata}"
            "\t</table>"
            "</body>"
            "</html>";
    };
};
```

Really don't know what I'm doing wrong here...

This is the error i'm getting:

Error   2   error C2086: 'const char *DataVerifier::Structure::strHTMLTemplate' : redefinition  c:\users\suzan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\test1\test1\testconstantsheader.cpp    7   1   Test1
Error   3   error C2086: 'const char *DataVerifier::Structure::strHTMLTemplate' : redefinition  c:\users\suzan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\test1\test1\testconstantsheader.cpp    7   1   Test1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header file contains a *definition* of an object `strHTMLTemplate` with external linkage. This is what leads to multiple definiton error.

Change the definition of `strHTMLTemplate` in the header file into a *non-defining declaration* by adding keyword `extern`

```
// TestConstantsHeader.h

namespace DataVerifier
{
    namespace Structure
    {
        extern const char *strHTMLTemplate;
    }
}
```

On top of that it probably makes sense to declare your pointer as `const char *const strHTMLTemplate`. It doesn't look like it is supposed to be modifiable.

Comment: Thank you so much man. I need to check why the "extern" keyword needs to be used.